# Error: Cannot find module 'serialport'. node.js, Arduino Yun

Tags: serial, arduino-yun, node.js

I carefully followed [Andy Sigler's tutorial](http://andysigler.com/teaching/nodejs-arduino-yun/) on how to setup node.js on Arduino Yun. But I'm getting this error "Cannot find module 'serialport'". my node.js file is in mnt/sda1/arduino/node folder. and I have installed node-serialport successfully through ssh. Kindly helpc

Comment: Did you check that post ["cannot find module 'serialport' using Node.js and Johnny-Five"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419702/cannot-find-module-serialport-using-node-js-and-johnny-five) ?

Comment: @J. Piquard I'm trying to use node.js in Arduino Yun. The post you mentioned is regarding installing node.js on a computer. It's not helpful..Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by following these steps:

Make a folder node_modules in mnt/sda1/

cd /mnt/sda1

wget http://wiki.linino.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:serialport-1.6.1_mips-25-ubuntu.tar.gz -O serialport-1.6.1_mips-25-ubuntu.tar.gz

run $ tar xvf serialport-1.6.1_mips-25-ubuntu.tar.gz -C /mnt/sda1/node_modules